# Javascript Get the parent id from a sub id

Tags: javascript

I have some code that will return me the name of the subcat clicked.

Here is the data below:

```
theData =    {
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": "661",
            "name": "some name",
            "description": "some description",
            "subcat": [
                {
                    "id": "662",
                    "name": "sub 1",
                    "translations": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "663",
                    "name": "sub 2",
                    "translations": null
                }
            ],
            "image": null
        },
        {
            "id": "657",
            "name": "some other name",
            "description": "",
            "subcat": [
                {
                    "id": "456",
                    "name": "sub 12",
                    "translations": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "656",
                    "name": "sub 15",
                    "translations": null
                }
            ],
            "image": null
        }
    ]
};
```

I need some way to find the parent id of the subcat name.

For example if I gave it "sub 15", it would return "661" which is the parent id

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? We need to see your code and some effort from you to try and solve the problem. This is not a free coding service.

Comment: what is the logic behind `"sub 15"` --> `"661"`? please explain.

Comment: Because at the point in the code I only have the subcat name ... So I use that to get the parent id so I can then do another query on another table which only matches the parent id

Comment: it seems, i have a different understanding of parent nodes. imho, a parent node is directly linked with the (own!) children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this .we have to iterate through all the data

```
[fiddle][1]
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tL1o6yd6/7/)

```
var input = "sub 15";
var id =-1;
for(var i=0;i<theData.categories.length;i++){
 if(theData.categories[i].subcat!=null){
   for(var j=0;j<theData.categories[i].subcat.length;j++){

     if(theData.categories[i].subcat[j].name==input){
     id= theData.categories[i].id;
     break;
   }
  }
 }
}
console.log(id)
```

Comment: This one is getting the id that belongs to the subcat .. I need it to get the parent id

Comment: This one works fine but if subcat is null it just breaks ... can't it not break when it finds a null?

Comment: Try setting the second subcat to null ... so: "subcat": null   ...it will just break ... I need it to continue without breaking

Comment: why cant you simply check subcat is null or not before entering into 2nd loop,check i have updated the code

Comment: @kevinj2017 is this you want??

Answer (score 2):

There's no way by default to access the "parent" of an object in Javascript -- it could be referenced in any number of other objects, or even by itself, so it's not possible to determine what the sole parent of an object is.

Instead, we'll just iterate through all the data until we find the matching id, and return `null` if we never find it. This solution counts on your IDs being unique entities, so if that's not the case, it'll have to be changed. With that said, here's an example:

```
function getParent(subID) {
    for (var i in theData.categories) {
        var parent = theData.categories[i];
        if ('subcat' in parent && 'length' in parent.subcat) {
            for (var j = 0; j < parent.subcat.length; j++) {
                if (parent.subcat[j].id === subID) {
                    return parent.id;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

If you don't like your function returning null, you can always alter it so that it returns `-1`, assuming that `-1` is out-of-band for your IDs. Note also that this is hardly an optimal solution, so if you're intending to use this for large amounts of data, you'll want to look into faster and/or more efficient search algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider more a generic solution, which searches for a given key and a value in the `subcat` array. Then take only the first object's `id`.

```js
function getParentId(key, value) {
    return (theData.categories.filter(function (a) {
        return a.subcat.some(function (b) {
            return b[key] === value;
        });
    })[0] || {}).id;
}

var theData = { categories: [{ id: 661, name: "some name", description: "some description", subcat: [{ id: 662, name: "sub 1", translations: null }, { id: 663, name: "sub 2", translations: null }], image: null }, { id: 657, name: "some other name", description: 0, subcat: [{ id: 456, name: "sub 12", translations: null }, { id: 656, name: "sub 15", translations: null }], image: null }] };

console.log(getParentId('name', 'sub 15'));
```

Comment: I need to parent Id not the id of the subcat ... the result expected here would be 661

Comment: why 661 with `'sub 15'`? please add this information to the question.

Comment: Because I need to parent Id

Comment: in the question you ask for an other number, which is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way but hope this will be useful

```
var getSubCat = []; // create an empty array to map parent id with sub name
var getCat = theData.categories; // get categories 
getCat.forEach(function(item) { // loop through categories
  item.subcat.forEach(function(elem) {
    getSubCat.push({
      id: item.id,  // this is parent id
      sub: elem.name // name inside each subcat object. Total 4 subcat object
    });
})
})
var parentId = getSubCat.filter(function(elem){ // filter the getSubCat array
    return elem.sub ==='sub 15' 
})[0].id    // parentId is an array, we need first object so [0]
alert(parentId)
```

Now I am pushing name inside each of `subcat` object. On requirement you can also push their id

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/awqj0s8h/6/)

Comment: This is returning the id from the given subcut ... I need to parent id which would be 661

Comment: please check the demo

Answer (score 0):

The below solution looks similar to furkle's solution. But here it uses jquery to iterate through the json objects.

```
function getParent(subID) {
    var parentId = null;
    $.each(theData.categories, function(i, v)
    {
        $.each(v.subcat, function(idx, obj){
            if(obj.name ==subID)
                parentId = v.id
        })
    })
    return parentId;
}
```